# Kivy: Check if a function is already scheduled

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Is there a way to check if a function has been scheduled already? I was looking at the `Clock` methods but didn't see anything I could use. I am trying to avoid a rescheduling(`Clock.unschedule(func)` -> `Clock.schedule_interval(func, dt)`) of a function unless it is already scheduled to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `kivy.clock.Clock.get_events()` to get the list of scheduled events:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock

<MyWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Print events"
        on_press: print(Clock.get_events())
    Button:
        text: "Add event"
        on_press: Clock.schedule_once(root.my_callback, 5)
""")

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def my_callback(self, arg):
        print("my_callback")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**OLD ANSWER**:

Not a very clean way, but you can examine the content of `kivy.clock.Clock._events` list.

Comment: This worked! I don't know if this is inadvisable for some reason, but it seems to work well.