# Kivy: delay change event for property / set properties in transactions

Tags: python, properties, transactions, kivy

Suppose I inherit from `Button`, adding an additional property:

```
class MyButton(Button):
    value = ObjectProperty(None)
```

Further suppose `value` and the button's `text` property are always changed together, say in a method

```
def update_data(self, data):
    self.text = data[0]
    self.value = data[1]
```

Now if I have a callback bound to `text`, it will not have access to the new `value`. Is there a way to delay triggering the event until the end of the `update_data` method (so that the object's state is consolidated, like a database transaction)? Just binding to `value` is unreliable, what if someone not familiar with the implementation changes the order of property assignment in another method?

Answer (score 1):

Your `on_text` method can schedule another method to be called as soon as possible using `Clock.schedule_once(callback, 0)`. An example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    my_button: my_button
    MyButton
        text: "..."
        id: my_button
    Button
        text: "value_text_order"
        on_press: root.value_text_order()
    Button
        text: "text_value_order"
        on_press: root.text_value_order()
""")

class MyButton(Button):
    value = ObjectProperty(None)
    my_button = ObjectProperty()

    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.on_test_and_value, 0)

    def on_test_and_value(self, *args):
        print("text:{} value: {}".format(self.text, self.value))

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def value_text_order(self, *args):
        self.my_button.value = 'b'
        self.my_button.text = 'a'

    def text_value_order(self, *args):
        self.my_button.text = 'c'
        self.my_button.value = 'd'

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach. I'm not yet going to accept it (yet), because there are several issues: One cannot  simply do the same for `on_value`, for that would then fire `self.on_test_and_value` twice. The other issue is that most elegantly, the original callbacks should have access to valid data, rather than adding a new callback. In the end, this might be what I have to use, though.

Comment: This might help with the first problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254796/kivy-check-if-a-function-is-already-scheduled